# How to place an idlelib Hovertip?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, python-idle

The current [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/idlelib/tooltip.py) of `Hovertip`, **packs** a `Label`. I overrided the `Hovertip` class to **place** it relative to mouse position like this:

```
class AbsoluteHovertip(Hovertip):
    def __init__(self, anchor_widget, text):
        super().__init__(anchor_widget, text)

    def showtip(self, x, y):
        if self.tipwindow:
            return
        self.tipwindow = tw = Toplevel(self.anchor_widget)
        tw.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        try:
            tw.tk.call("::tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle", "style", tw._w,
                       "help", "noActivates")
        except TclError:
            pass

        self.position_window()
        self.showcontents(x, y)
        self.tipwindow.update_idletasks()
        self.tipwindow.lift()
    
    def showcontents(self, x, y):
        label = Label(self.tipwindow, text=self.text, justify=LEFT,
                      background="#ffffe0", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1)
        label.place(x=x+10, y=y+10)
```

I am using it like this inside a `Treeview`:

```
# self.tv is Treeview
# self.htip is AbsoluteHovertip(self.tv, "")
# self.events is just a list

def treeview_tooltip(self, event):
    row = self.tv.identify_row(event.y)
    column = self.tv.identify_column(event.x)
    values = self.tv.item(row, "values")
    if column == "#2":
        index = int(values[0])
        ev = self.events[index]
        self.htip.text = int(ev.id)
        self.htip.showtip(event.x, event.y)
    elif column == "#3":
        text = values[2]
        if len(text) >= 30:
            self.htip.text = text
            self.htip.showtip(event.x, event.y)
    else:
        self.htip.hidetip()
    self.tv.tk.call(self.tv, "tag", "remove", "highlight")
    self.tv.tk.call(self.tv, "tag", "add", "highlight", row)
```

However instead of showing up as expected, a square box of about 100x100 or more shows up below the `Treeview` at the same place a normal `HoverTip` would appear.

Comment: as for me it uses `place()` or `pack()` only to put `Label` inside `Toplevel` but it can't change `tooltip` position. You would have to change position of `Toplevel`, not `Label`. It would need to change `position_window()` to change `tooltip` position.

Comment: @furas I gave up on this, and now using a `Label` with an `after` event handler. There are some warnings in the implementation of the `position_window` method advising against what you say

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this and your `showtip` override gave me an idea. Inside `showtip` there is a call to `position_window` so I override that and was able to change the position of the tip window. You can also do it with `self.tipwindow.geometry()` (probably in any override) if you can get the right position that you need. I needed relative repositioning so override `position_window` worked well for me. Below I am repositioning the `tipwindow` by the width of the anchor widget. I also overloaded `showcontents` so that I could style the tip window.

```
class Tip(Hovertip):
    def position_window(self):
        """(re)-set the tooltip's screen position"""
        x, y = self.get_position()
        root_x = self.anchor_widget.winfo_rootx() + x - self.anchor_widget.winfo_width()
        root_y = self.anchor_widget.winfo_rooty() + y
        self.tipwindow.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (root_x, root_y))

    def showcontents(self):
        label = Label(self.tipwindow, text=self.text, justify=LEFT,
                      relief=SOLID, font=("Segoe UI", 12), borderwidth=0,
                      background=background, foreground=foreground,
                      padx=10, pady=10)
        label.pack()

Tip(set_btn, "Settings", hover_delay=0)
```